# Make all EditText not editable together

Tags: android, android-edittext

I searched and found ways to make a single EditText not editable, such as

1. `edittext.setKeyListener(null);`
2. set `EditText` as `android:focusable="false"`

However, the problem with these methods is that I need to get references to each of the `EditText` views in my layout and individually implement the above statements. Is there a way by which I can make all EditText views in a layout not editable?

The application is this: I have a 'Display and Edit' activity, where the user is shown the current record in the database. At this point the displayed text should be read only. If required, he clicks an edit button and then the EditText views become editable.

I tried setting `android:inputType="none"` and `android:focusable="false"` in the root `ViewGroup` but that didn't work. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to achieve this programmatically,

```
public void setupUI(View view, boolean editable) {
    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText)view).setFocusable(editable);
        //Here you can add any other code that needed to be done while changing focus of a particular edit text
        return;
    }
    //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupUI(innerView, editable);
        }
    }
}
```

Provide this method with your parent view of your fragment or activity.

When you are clicking edit button pass the parent view and true(i.e, editable) to the method and after editing pass parent view and false(i.e, not editable) instead.

Comment: Thanx, but last call to setupUI would also include the boolean parameter editable right?

Comment: I removed the boolean editable argument in the function declaration and it works fine. Thanx. The views light up though when clicked. I guess I can include a command to make the view unclickable too.

Comment: Amazing bit of code!! Esp the recursive part. Elegant and concise. Thanx!!

Answer (score 1):

From [`android:descendantFocusability` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability):

> Defines the relationship between the ViewGroup and its descendants when looking for a View to take focus.

Apply this to the parent of those `EditText`s:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

This will result the `ViewGroup` to block its descendants from receiving focus.

Comment: This works, thanx! Although, the EditText views still light up when clicked. Would be great if there was some way to disable clickable too. Couldn't find a similar attribute for that.

Comment: Apply `android:focusable="false"` to `EditText`.

Comment: but I would have to do that to each EditText separately, which is the whole problem.

Comment: Have you applied `android:focusable="false"` to the root layout?

Comment: That also didnt work, but your answer worked i.e android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants", just the minor problem that it responds visually to clicks